# How to load local shared swf file on site?

Tags: html, flash, object-tag, shared-file

I have a local site in my system. The site index page contains an object and embed tag to load a SWF file.

I have a shared folder in my local system. This folder contains number of SWF files. It can access by other machine using my system IP path.

I am trying to load swf from the shared folder, its not get load. The code is;

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width = "400" height= "400" id="objFlash" align="middle">
       <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
       <param name="src" value= "file:\\\\52.234.85.84\Sites\abc\remoteasset.swf" />
       <param name="quality" value="high" />
       <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
       <param name="menu" value="false" />
       <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
       <embed src="file:\\\\52.234.85.84\Sites\abc\remoteasset.swf" quality="high" menu="false" wmode="opaque" width="400" height="400" id="objFlash" name="objFlash" allowScriptAccess="always" allowFullScreen="true" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />        
</object>
```

Any one can suggest, How to load shared folder flash files into site in object/embed tag?

Answer (score 0):

Your embed src is wrong, it should be file:\\52.234.85.84\Sites\abc\remoteasset.swf

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried like "file:\\52.234.85.84\Sites\abc\remoteasset.swf". But its not working.

Comment: Go here http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html
and add 52.234.85.84\Sites